# Why am i getting null as output by using union in mySql?

Tags: mysql

```
Equilateral: It's a triangle with sides of equal length.
Isosceles: It's a triangle with sides of equal length.
Scalene: It's a triangle with sides of differing lengths.
Not A Triangle: The given values of A, B, and C don't form a triangle.
```

**A,B AND C ARE COLUMNS NAME IN The TRIANGLES table**

**SQL-Query**

```
(
SELECT distinct 
CASE 
when (a=b and a<>c) 
or (b=c and a<>c) 
or (a=c and a<>b) 
then 'Isosceles' 
end 
from triangles
) 
union
(
SELECT distinct 
CASE 
when a=b 
and b=c 
then 'Equilateral' 
end 
from triangles
)
union 
(
SELECT distinct 
CASE 
when a!=b 
and b!=c 
and a!=c 
then 'Scalene' 
end 
from triangles
)
union
( 
SELECT distinct 
CASE 
when a+b<c 
or b+c <a 
or a+c<b 
then 'Not A Triangle' 
end 
from triangles
);
```

**OUTPUT**

NULL

Isosceles

Equilateral

Scalene

Not A Triangle

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT distinct 
CASE 
when (a=b and a<>c) 
or (b=c and a<>c) 
or (a=c and a<>b) 
then 'Isosceles' 
when a=b 
and b=c 
then 'Equilateral' 
when a!=b 
and b!=c 
and a!=c 
then 'Scalene' 
else 'Not A Triangle' 
end 
from triangles
```

You can change conditions as you wish.